# error: called object is not a function

Tags: c

Trying to make an array of arrays of floats using pointers

```
int main(void)
{
    int num_of_dataSets;
    float **dataSets;   
    int i;
    float *get_data;

    printf("Enter the number of data sets: \n");
    scanf( "%d " , &num_of_dataSets);
    dataSets = malloc(num_of_dataSets * sizeof(float) );

    for( i=0; i < num_of_dataSets; i++)
    {
        *(dataSets + i) = get_data();
    }

}


float* get_data()
{
    float *float_list_data;
    int j;
    int num_of_floats;

    printf("Enter the data: \n");
    scanf("%d" , &num_of_floats);

    float_list_data = malloc( num_of_floats * sizeof(float) );
    return float_list_data;
}
```

Getting error called object "get_data" is not a function.
I can't get the error to go away. What am I missing?!

Comment: remove `float *get_data;` and add `float *get_data(void);` above `main`.

Comment: If you format your code properly, it would be easier to find the problem in it.

Comment: Or if you want to declare function `get_data()` inside `main()` you can do so, but you must declare it *as a function*.  You have declared that name as a variable, and that declaration shadows the function name.  The declaration of a function has a parenthesized argument list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You have a local variable called `get_data` in your function already, in addition to the function called `get_data`.  Rename either one of them to avoid this naming confusion.

   EDIT: It seems you don't even use the variable `float* get_data;` in `main()`.  You can just remove it.
2. If you call a function that the compiler can't find or doesn't know about, it assumes that it's just linked to from elsewhere (like, some other library that the linker knows about), and returns an `int`.  You call `get_data()` before you define `get_data()` below `main()` in your code.  To avoid this error, prototype the function `get_data()` before `main()`, like so:

   ```
   float* get_data();
   int main(void)
   { 
       /* Your code here */
   }
   float* get_data()
   {
       /* Your code here */
   }
   ```

Comment: You could also simply define the entire function before main, but good to know how to use function prototypes for this. It's nice to use a function prototype so that you can leave main at the top of the source.

Comment: @KennethWilke In this case, you can just define `get_data()` before `main()`, but in general, it's best practice to prototype all functions to deal with things like various functions calling one another - if you have a circular call chain (A calls B calls A), then which function goes first?

Answer (score 1):

When compiler parses your code then it gets `get_data` name twice once as function name and as `float *` too. Now when it reaches a function call it simply checks the symbol table and then it gets confused and says that it can't find the function named `get_data` as it was already declared as `float*`.